# Why is the logical NOT operator in C-style languages "!" and not "~~"?

Tags: java, c#, c++, c

For binary operators we have both bitwise and logical operators:

```
& bitwise AND
| bitwise OR

&& logical AND
|| logical OR
```

NOT (a unary operator) behaves differently though. There is ~ for bitwise and ! for logical.

I recognize NOT is a unary operation as opposed to AND and OR but I cannot think of a reason why the designers chose to deviate from the principle that single is bitwise and double is logical here, and went for a different character instead. I guess you could read it wrong, like a double bitwise operation that would always return the operand value. But that does not seem a real problem to me.

Is there a reason I am missing?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Logical_equivalents

Comment: Because if !! meant logical not, how would I turn 42 into 1? :)

Comment: Would `~~` then not have been more consistent for logical NOT, if you follow the pattern that the logical operator is a doubling of the bitwise operator?

Comment: First, if it was for consistency it would have been ~ and ~~ The doubling of and and or is associated to the short circuit; and the logical not doesn’t have a short circuit.

Comment: I suspect the underlying design reason is visual clarity and distinction, in the typical use cases. The binary (that is, two-operand) operators are infix (and tend to be separated by spaces), whereas the unary operators are prefix (and tend not to be spaced).

Comment: @candied_orange Why would you want to turn 42 into 1? You would want it to be interpreted as either false or true. This could be just the way it works now, with 0 being false and anything else being true.

Comment: @Christophe Could you elaborate on that in an answer please? You seem to suggest there is a relationship with electronics but I do not quite understand what you are saying.

Comment: @MartinMaat, I had to think for a moment myself, but I think he means short-circuiting operators - that is, binary operators (e.g. and-also, or-else) that evaluate the first operand, and only evaluate the second conditionally if the result is not already determined by the first operand.

Comment: @Steve nope. Hang on...

Comment: @MartinMaat & Steve, because I wanna be clever. I'll let [Armen explain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10307288/1493294).

Comment: In other words because !!!!42==1 looks silly

Comment: Interesting question, but isn't it it off topic?

Comment: @candied_orange That (link) did not quite answer my question but was an interesting addition nonetheless. Your writing in riddles makes sense now.

Comment: @Filip Some people appear to think it is a matter of opinion. As it turns out that is only the case if you do not know your computer science history!  :->

Comment: @martin maat yeah sorry !! used to be a well known c idiom. While I wasn't looking I've apparently gotten old.

Comment: @candied_orange - but !! is alive and well in JavaScript :)

Comment: @MartinMaat - I didn't mean to say that it's a matter of opinion, but unless I'm mistaken, questions that are solely about some random aspect of CS history and questions about why people working on a product made some very specific decision aren't really on topic (generally speaking).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović my favorite meta answer on history questions is [this](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8215/131624). I'm gonna miss having Robert Harvey as our mod. Who's gonna delete my inane prattling now?

Comment: As some comments have already alluded to (and for those who don't want to follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10307288/1493294), `!!foo` is a not-uncommon (not not common?) idiom. It normalizes a zero-or-nonzero argument to `0` or `1`.

Comment: Clearly this inconsistency should be corrected immediately. And let's fix the logical exclusive-or operator as `^^` while we're about it, this `!=` business is just confusing.

Comment: I think you answered it yourself already, because one is unary while the others are binary.  Multiple concatenated unary operators mean apply that operator multiple times, so it can't be it's own separate symbol.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Strangely, the history of C-style programming language doesn’t start with C.

Dennis Ritchie explains well the challenges of C’s birth in [this article](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html).

When reading it, it becomes obvious that C inherited a part of its language design from its predecessor [BCPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCPL), and especially the operators. The section “Neonatal C” of the aforementioned article explains how BCPL’s `&` and `|` were enriched with two new operators `&&` and `||`.  The reasons were:

- different priority was required due to its use in combination with  `==`
- different evaluation logic: left-to-right evaluation with [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)  (i.e when `a` is `false` in `a&&b`, `b` is not evaluated).

Interestingly, this doubling does not create any ambiguity for the reader: `a && b` will not be misinterpreted as `a(&(&b))`.  From a parsing point of view, there is no ambiguity either: `&b` could make sense if `b` were an lvalue, but it would be a pointer whereas the bitwise `&` would require an integer operand, so the logical AND would be the only reasonable choice.

BCPL already used `~` for bitwise negation. So from a point of view of consistency,  it could have been doubled to give a `~~` to give it its logical meaning.  Unfortunately this would have been extremely ambiguous since `~` is a unary operator: `~~b` could also mean `~(~b))`.  This is why another symbol had to be chosen for the missing negation.

Comment: *"cannot be misinterpreted ... since it is a binary operator"* - does that not put the cart before the horse, since it is the task of the parser to determine (as a prior question) whether a particular sequence of characters is a binary operator, or an unary operator applied twice? Presumably it is the order of precedence or a fixed rule that resolves the ambiguity - it is not inherently unambiguous.

Comment: The parser is unable to disambiguate the two situations, therefore the language designers must do so.

Comment: @Steve: Indeed, there are many similar problems already in C and C-like languages. When the parser sees `(t)+1` is that an addition of `(t)` and `1` or is it a cast of `+1` to type `t`?  C++ design had to solve the problem of how to lex templates containing `>>` correctly. And so on.

Comment: @Steve I was indeed a little bit too fast in my formulation.  I've edited to present two aspects:  the human reader and the parser.  Hope this clarifies the point you've raised.

Comment: `&&` isn't actually disambiguated from two instances of `&` at parser level; it's disambiguated at tokenization level. If you tried to design it so the disambiguation was based on two `&`s not making sense in the type system, then the parser would have to understand the types of expressions, and `a & & b` would be a valid logical AND expression.

Comment: @user2357112 I think the point is that it's okay to have the tokenizer blindly take `&&` as a single `&&` token and not as two `&` tokens, because the `a & (&b)` interpretation isn't a reasonable thing to write, so a human would never have meant that and been surprised by the compiler treating it as `a && b`. Whereas both `!(!a)` and `!!a` are possible things for a human to mean, so it's a bad idea for the compiler to resolve the ambiguity with an arbitrary tokenization-level rule.

Comment: `!!` is not only possible/reasonable to write, but the canonical "convert to boolean" idiom.

Comment: How would `~~` introduce any more ambiguity than `++` and `--`?

Comment: @dan04 The expression `a+` is not valid.  `a++` is valid  `a++b` is not valid.    `a+++b` is syntactically valid. `a+++++b` is [not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5341202/3723423). Until two the human reader has no problem, starting with three you wonder about priorities: is it `a++ + b` or `a + ++b` and you'd end up on SO to find out if your interpretation is portable ;-)

Comment: @dan04 For `~~` I see it as ambiguous because ~~ could mean two different things in any context.  But you are right: there could be a syntactical rule to use the longest token to disambiguate the grammar. I suppose we'd get used to (but it'll be a lot more wordy).  Compared to `++`, `~a` would be valid, `~~a` would be valid, `~ ~ a` (see the spaces ?) would be valid but with a different meaning. So it would be error prone. In addition you'd have to define the priorities applicable for `~~~`. Yes, for the grammar it's ok, but for humans, the potential problems start at two.

Comment: I think dan04 is referring to the ambiguity of `--a` vs `-(-a)`, both of which are valid syntactically but have different semantics.

Comment: @Ruslan that's the point I tried to make in the second comment for dan. `a--b` [doesn't compile](https://ideone.com/OcVoN1) at all.  `a - -b` would compile.  With ~  all these forms with one or two tilde would compile with different results. This is why I say it's ambiguous.  I agree that additional rules could be introduced; but it would be like for `++++` where we would start to wonder it's legal and what are the priorities: the (human) ambiguity makes it error prone.

Comment: `!!` can also emerge from the use of macros.

Comment: The only thing I would add is that references to "BCPL" here are references to one concrete syntax for BCPL. If you go to an early 1967 reference manual for BCPL at https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/bcpl.pdf you find that it used abstract syntax for operators because each machine had a different character repertoire. The abstract syntax used operators like ∧ and ∨; the concrete implementation that I programmed in represented these as /\ and \/ (slash-backslash and backslash-slash, in case that's unclear).

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for this interesting information !

Comment: If "logical not" had been written as `~~` then the "convert to bool operator" would just have been `~~~~` - which I quite like for it's length.

Comment: I don’t think this explanation is correct. The language already had many situations that could have been ambiguous, and resolved them with the maximal munch rule. The designers allowed, for example, `a=-b;`.

Comment: @Davislor what is ambiguous in a=-b ?

Comment: @Christophe in B, the predecessor to C where `!` was introduced, `a=-b` has the same meaning as `a -= b` in C. But, if not for the maximal munch rule, it could also be parsed as `a = -b`.

Comment: @Davislor I don’t remember ever having seen this in K&R.

Comment: @Davislor The doubling of logical operators in C is for short circuit only. There is no short circuit for an unary not.  So no doubling. Other potential ambiguous doublings are increment/decrement, and these are not logical operators. If you don’t trust me, read Denis Ritchie’s article linked in my answer: he should know better, since he co-invented the language ;-)

Comment: @Christophe It was changed in 1976, according to Ritchie. Others remained in place: early compilers did not enforce the type system strictly, so `a & &b` would’ve worked. You still cannot write `a--b` even though the only sensible thing it could mean is `a - -b`, and `a/*b` will start a comment instead of divide by the value `b` points to. The tokenizer has never been (specified as) complex enough to interpret a stream of tokens based on what would make sense in the grammar.

Comment: @Christophe I discuss short-circuiting in my answer below. It was important, but not the only reason.

Comment: @Davislor I think both responses are complementary (this why I upvoted yours when you wrote it). OP wondered why it was not doubled operator as all logical operators, and my focus is to explain that doubled bitwise operator is not for logic but for other reasons. This takes away the consistency argument. My explanation are backed by Ritchie’s paper. I also give a plausible reason why doubled negation was not a good idea (and my argument is true for B as well, because they could have come up with doubling in B as well). Your answer addresses the historical path. But not consistency issue.

Comment: @Davislor because the language designers could have made the choice of consistency, if they would really have associated double ops whit logical op, to take another operator for the logical not (for retrocompatibility they could even have accepted ! as alias for ~~ before to deprecate it). But they didn‘t. Because they didn‘t have to. Because doubling was  made for adressing priority and short circuit (and not to mean „logical“, as our exchange on the missing logical xor seems to confirm).In all fairness, despite your downvote, I‘ll let my upvote on your interesting & relevant contribution ;-)

Comment: @Christophe This is starting to get into speculation. But I think the historical timeline goes the other way: `!` was introduced before `&&` or `||` were created to be consistent with. I suggest in my answer that it might have been inspired by `!=`.

Answer (score 50):

> I cannot think of a reason why the designers chose to deviate from the principle that single is bitwise and double is logical here,

That's not the principle in the first place; once you realize that, it makes more sense.

The better way to think of `&` vs `&&` is not *binary* and *Boolean*.  The better way is to think of them as *eager* and *lazy*.  The `&` operator executes the left and right side and then computes the result. The `&&` operator executes the left side, and then executes the right side only if necessary to compute the result.

Moreover, instead of thinking about "binary" and "Boolean", think about what is really happening. The "binary" version is just *doing the Boolean operation on an array of Booleans that has been packed into a word*.

So let's put it together. Does it make any sense to do a lazy operation *on an array of Booleans*?  No, because there is no "left side" to check first. There are 32 "left sides" to check first.  So we restrict the lazy operations to a *single* Boolean, and that's where your intuition that one of them is "binary" and one is "Boolean" comes from, but that is a *consequence* of the design, not the design itself!

And when you think of it that way, it becomes clear why there is no `!!` and no `^^`.  Neither of those operators have the property that you can skip analyzing one of the operands; there is no "lazy" `not` or `xor`.

Other languages make this more clear; some languages use `and` to mean "eager and" but `and also` to mean "lazy and", for instance.  And other languages also make it more clear that `&` and `&&` are not "binary" and "Boolean"; in C# for instance, both versions can take Booleans as operands.

Comment: Thank you. This is the real eye opener for me. Too bad I cannot accept two answers.

Comment: I don't think this is a good way to think of `&` and `&&`. While eagerness is one of the differences between `&` and `&&`, `&` behaves completely differently from an eager version of `&&`, particularly in languages where `&&` supports types other than a dedicated boolean type.

Comment: @user2357112: We designed C# very carefully so that `&` and `&&` have logically consistent behaviour for non-Boolean types; what "other languages" did you have in mind?

Comment: For example, in C and C++, `1 & 2` has a completely different result from `1 && 2`.

Comment: Assuming 'eager' vs 'lazy' is the main distinction, why even have both ! and ~? A single one would be completely sufficient and lead to no confusion.

Comment: @user2357112, I must admit, I thought the explanation quite absurd until I saw who had wrote it, and then I paused for breath. It is true what Eric says that it is best to see `&&` as the 'lazy logical', but there is no corresponding 'eager logical' (except for boolean types where there is inherently no logical/bitwise distinction), so we have only eager bitwise and lazy logical. So Eric has touched on our problem: laziness and logicality (or bitwisity?) are two unrelated qualities of operators, and `&` differs from `&&` on both counts.

Comment: @ZizyArcher, because the bitwise-NOT inverts the bits (which may not equal zero after being applied to a non-zero operand, unless all bits were set or unless the type was a boolean), whereas the logical-NOT yields zero if the operand is non-zero (if *any* bits are set).

Comment: @user2357112: C# was designed to *fix* many of the oddities of C and C++, while preserving as much familiarity as possible. C's odd behaviour in this regard stems from the lack of a bool type in the language; once you add that, you can come up with a more consistent operator design, as C# did.

Comment: @ZizyArcher: As I noted in the comment above, the decision to omit a `bool` type in C has knock-on effects. We need both `!` and `~` because one means "treat an int as a single Boolean" and one means "treat an int as a packed array of Booleans". If you have separate bool and int types then you can have just one operator, which in my opinion would have been the better design, but we're almost 50 years late on that one. C# preserves this design for familiarity.

Comment: @Steve: If the answer seems absurd then I have made a poorly expressed argument somewhere, and we ought not to rely on an argument from authority. Can you say more about what seems absurd about it?

Comment: I suspect that there may be a disconnect between people who think of "logical operator" as being "cast each argument to a boolean first" (which seems a bit odd since you really are wanting a boolean type) vs. those people who think of "C is a scripting language for assembly and so of course I sometimes want to treat bits as numbers and sometimes I want to treat them as booleans".

Comment: This is an interesting take. But I can still think of ways to conceptualize a lazy Boolean operation on packed arrays of Booleans. It's just that the laziness would run first along the packed arrays, rather than the sequence of operations.

Comment: @senderle please say more! I am intrigued by your idea but not following your train of thought

Comment: To be clear, I'm thinking in general, not in the C, etc. context specifically. But suppose your final step lazily reduces an array of booleans to a single boolean using `and`. You could lazily zip together two boolean arrays, lazily generate a single array using element-wise `and`, and perform your lazy reduction on the result. If the first value of the first array is `False`, then no values in the second boolean array will ever need to be evaluated. Probably not practical in most cases, of course.

Comment: @senderle: Ah, I see what you're saying. So in the context of C, the semantics of your proposed `x && f()` on ints `x` and `f()` are the semantics of `x == 0 ? 0 : (x & f())`.  That does make some sense, but I agree that it is likely too special-purpose to make it into a mainstream language.

Comment: @EricLippert, I only thought your argument absurd *at first*. As I say in my comment following some reflection, there are really two separate qualities to these operators. First, whether they are eager or lazy, and second whether they are logical or bitwise. One could theoretically have a lazy bitwise-AND, which did not even evaluate the second operand, if the first was zero, and thus the bitwise result must be zero regardless of the second operand - but such an operation is not implemented... (1/2)

Comment: ...You invite us to forget about the logical/bitwise distinction and instead consider the eager/lazy distinction. But both seem relevant, and not all combinations are implemented. The unary operations do not have a lazy version, because the concept is inapplicable. The bitwise AND and OR operations do not have a lazy version, probably because they map directly to assembly instructions which operate a word-at-a-time, and there is no prospect of efficiency improvements to justify separate lazy versions. (2/2).

Comment: @Steve: Well I'm glad it seemed less absurd as time went on. :)  I agree that it often comes down to details of assembly language, but in fact there are some true oddities here. For example, PDP 11 assembly language's shift instruction takes an operand that is from -31 to 32, so one naturally assumes that a sensible language would make an operator `x shift y` where `y` can be between -31 and 32. But no, C unnecessarily gives us *two* operators `<<` and `>>` and requires the operand to be *non negative* and then this crazy design is copied into Java, C#, C++...

Comment: @Steve: But upon more reflection you see that, oh, the *original* PDP 11 did not have this instruction, and in fact it had *shift right by one* and *shift left by one*, and now you realize that the authors of the compiler probably did not want to generate the code that chose which instruction to use at runtime based on the sign of the operand; the author of the code *probably* knows which direction it is going to shift, and this saves on code size, back when code size was important.  So once again we see that design is a process of compromises.

Comment: @Steve: But it is downright vexing that our language design today is still so heavily influenced by the small details of the instruction set of a machine from the 1970s.

Comment: @EricLippert, indeed, it is surprising how terribly long a legacy some design decisions can have, exerting a dead hand of influence even when the circumstances which determined the original decisions have long since disappeared! I would guess what some see as paying the cost of compromise, are what others see as reaping the benefits of integration - including, often, integration merely with existing popular understandings or expectations (of the meaning of programming statements and syntax, of the exact behaviour of operations, etc.)

Comment: @EricLippert: It would sometimes be nifty if modern HW had a shift instruction that took a signed shift count.  IDK if it would make O(1) hardware implementations (barrel shifters) significantly larger; they already usually support rotates where any bit can end up anywhere.  But sometimes it's handy that the hardware masks ([x86](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sal:sar:shl:shr)) or saturates ([ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489h/CIHDDCIF.html)) the shift count when it's outside the 0..31 range. Perhaps if C had chosen differently, HW would have followed.

Comment: @EricLippert: the only problem / absurdity / thing that looks wrong is early on when you suggest that lazy vs. eager is the difference *instead of* bitwise vs. logical.  As you later say, both those properties are essential to understanding the operators.  Perhaps phrasing like "as well as bitwise vs. boolean, the other key difference is eager vs. laze.  This difference also informs which operators are needed." (That 2nd sentence of my suggestion is weak, but I like the first one that introduces eager vs. lazy without suggesting that bitwise vs. boolean isn't important or worth thinking about.

Comment: @EricLippert *"`<<` and `>>` and requires the operand to be non negative and then this crazy design is copied into Java, C#, ..."* ... not exactly. At least in Java, both operands may be negative and the result is well-defined (and things like `x >> -1` are used to extract the sign bit).

Comment: @maaartinus: I had no idea! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @EricLippert You're welcome. [These strange rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) follow how most CPUs work.

Answer (score 23):

#### TL;DR

C inherited the `!` and `~` operators from another language. Both `&&` and `||` were added years later by a different person.

### Long Answer

Historically, C developed out of the early languages B, which was based on BCPL, which was based on CPL, which was based on Algol.

[Algol](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/ALGOL/report/Algol68_revised_report-AB.pdf), the great-granddaddy of C++, Java and C#, defined true and false in a way that came to feel intuitive to programmers: “truth values which, regarded as a binary number (true corresponding to 1 and false to 0), is the same as the intrinsic integral value”.  However, one disadvantage of this is that logical and bitwise not cannot be the same operation: On any modern computer, `~0` equals -1 rather than 1 and `~1` equals -2 rather than 0.  (Even on some sixty-year-old mainframe where `~0` represents -0 or `INT_MIN`, `~0 != 1` on every CPU ever made, and the C language standard has required it for many years, while most of its daughter languages don’t even bother to support sign-and-magnitude or one’s-complement at all.)

Algol worked around this by having different modes and interpreting operators differently in boolean and integral mode.  That is, a bitwise operation was one on integer types, and a logical operation was one on boolean types.

BCPL had a separate boolean type, but [a single `not` operator](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/bcpl.html), for both bitwise and logical not.  The way this early forerunner of C made that work was:

> The Rvalue of true is a bit pattern entirely composed of ones; the Rvalue of false is zero.
>
> Note that  `true =  ~ false`

(You’ll observe that the term *rvalue* has evolved to mean something completely different in C-family languages.  We would today call that “the object representation” in C.)

This definition would allow logical and bitwise not to use the same machine-language instruction.  If C had gone that route, header files the world over would say `#define TRUE -1`.

But [the B programming language](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/bref.html) was weakly-typed, and had no boolean or even floating-point types.  Everything was the equivalent of `int` in its successor, C.  This made it a good idea for the language to define what happened when a program used a value other than true or false as a logical value. It first defined a truthy expression as “not equal to zero.”  This was efficient on the minicomputers on which it ran, which had a CPU zero flag.

There was, at the time, an alternative: the same CPUs also had a negative flag, and BCPL’s truth value was -1, so B might have instead defined all negative numbers as truthy and all non-negative numbers as falsy.  (There is one remnant of this approach: UNIX, developed by the same people at the same time, defines all error codes as negative integers.  Many of its system calls return one of several different negative values on failure.)  So be thankful: it could have been worse!

But defining `TRUE` as `1` and `FALSE` as `0` in B meant that the identity `true =  ~ false` no longer held, and it had dropped the strong typing that allowed Algol to disambiguate between bitwise and logical expressions.  That required a new logical-not operator, and the designers picked `!`, possibly because not-equal-to was already `!=`, which looks sort of like a vertical bar through an equal sign.  They didn’t follow the same convention as `&&` or `||` because neither one yet existed.

Arguably, they should have: the `&` operator in B is broken as designed. In B and in C, `1 & 2 == FALSE` even though `1` and `2` are both truthy values, and there is no intuitive way to express the logical operation in B.  That was one mistake C tried to partly rectify by adding `&&` and `||`, but the main concern at the time was to finally get short-circuiting to work, and make programs run faster.  The proof of this is that there is no `^^`: `1 ^ 2` is a truthy value even though both its operands are truthy, but it cannot benefit from short-circuiting.

Comment: +1. I think this is a pretty good guided tour around the evolution of these operators.

Comment: BTW, sign/magnitude and one's complement machines also need separate bitwise vs. logical negation, even if the input is already booleanized.  `~0` (all bits set) is one's complement negative zero (or a trap representation). Sign/magnitude `~0` is a negative number with maximum magnitude.

Comment: @PeterCordes You’re absolutely right. I was just focusing on two’s-complement machines because they’re a lot more important. Maybe it’s worth a footnote.

Comment: I think my comment is sufficient, but yeah, maybe a parenthetical (doesn't work for 1's complement or sign/magnitude either) would be a good edit.

Comment: According to K&R explanations, the main purpose of short circuit is not to make it faster, but to allow conditions that avoid hard failures (e.g: `if (i!=0 && k/i>x) ` will never lead to a division by 0, which would not be guaranteed without short circuits; same for `p==NULL || *p=='\0'`). Then, C before 1978 K&R was not yet C but a development version of it, isn’t it? Finally, I do not get from your explanations why the designers dit chose ! an not ~~ (which was in fact the question that we had to answer). You just say they picked the first. But why?

Comment: Btw there is indeed only a bitwise ^ and no ^^. Why? It would make sense to have a logical xor as well (it‘d be more convenient than (a||b)&&!(a&&b) ). But xor does‘t allow for a short circuit: you always have to evaluate both operands.

Comment: @Christophe The reason C uses `!` is that B did. B was not designed by the same people who came up with `&&` and `||`, and they did not realize at the time that the logical operators would need to be extended. Interestingly, B was based on an early version of BCPL, rather than later ones, which used `!` rather than `*` as the dereference operator. C might look very different otherwise!